# why in javascript i cant create object in this function?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs, peer

i have a problem with creating object inside my function
i know its a void function but i don't need to return any data

```
let btnConnect = document.getElementById('connect')
let btnConnectedDrive = document.getElementById('ConnectedDrive')

function createPeer() {
    let myPeer = new Peer()
    console.log(myPeer.id)
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/myapp/room/' + game_id + '/');
    socket.onopen = () => socket.send(JSON.stringify(
        {
            'username': user,
            'PeerId': myPeer.id
        }
    ),)

}

btnConnect.onclick = () => createPeer();
```

now when i log myPeer.id its `null` and same on the server
what do you think solution is ?
hope you have a very nice time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://peerjs.com/docs/#api):

> Other peers can connect to this peer using the provided ID. If no ID is given, **one will be generated by the brokering server**.

And the example:

> ```
>  peer.on('open', function(id) {
>    console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
>  });
> ```

It doesn't have an ID because you haven't waited for it to connect to the brokering server and be issued with one.

Comment: that's true but i cant understand why it have an ID outside of function

Comment: I don't understand why you think it does.

Comment: well i can see my server response to myPeer.id when its created outside of `createPeer()` ===> e06880b7-ec1e-4110-8021-5cb91a794584 instead of `null`

Comment: @Mohammad — The time delay between calling `new Peer()` and the user clicking the button counts as having "waited for it to connect to the brokering server" (although its a shonky approach).